# Why python's logging module stopped working suddenly?

Tags: python, python-3.8

For years I have been working with python and running massive data processes that run for hours or days. So logging for me is critical. I have been using logging module for a long time with no issues except today; a process that I need to run stopped writing the log file.

If a run the next code, nothing goes to the log file:

```
import logging

_log_file_name = "LOGGER_TEST.log"
logging.basicConfig(filename=_log_file_name, format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s",
                            level=logging.INFO)

logging.info("HELLO")
logging.info("BYE")
```

what Am I doing wrong?

I'm running this code from Jupyter
And my process I'm running it from PyCharm and from Ubuntu, not even writing the log file from any of them.

Thanks!!

Comment: You are writing to the current working directory... perhaps its just different than you think it is. Try an absolute path or print what `os.getcwd()` is to see if its there.

Comment: Hi, tdelaney, thanks, but this code is in fact creating the log file, but HELLO and BYE are not being written into the file. In other process I'm trying to run is not even creating the log file, and I'm working with absolute paths. Anyways I will follow your advice to double check

Comment: I fix the issue, the cause I haven't clear though but it seems that has to do with some "ordering" on imports and some of the imported modules initialized logging before my class. Once I leave my process running (I have lost many hours because of this issue) I will try to code a procedure to replicate it and then I will  publish it here as an answer. I found the inspiration on this link: https://python-forum.io/Thread-Logging-module-stopped-working

Comment: I was was wondering if that was the problem but wasn't sure if `basicConfig` raises an error in that case. Generally, if you have a module that is expected to be imported, it should consume logging but not configure it. That's usually the job of the top level script.

Comment: Wow, thanks for posting your answer here, i just ran into this in python 3.8 
I also had to setup `basicconfig` before my other imports >:/

Answer (score 1):

I assume either some module or jupyter notebook (ipython) is calling the `logging.basicConfig` before your script is calling it. Subsequent calls to `basicConfig()` has no effect and does not throw any error. To quote from official docs:

> The call to basicConfig() should come before any calls to debug(), info() etc. As it’s intended as a one-off simple configuration facility, only the first call will actually do anything: subsequent calls are effectively no-ops.

So try to import `logging` and configuring logging at the start of the script